# Verificar erros em arquivo PHP executado por url externa

Tags: php

Bom dia,

eu estou trabalhando com o serviço de *checkout* da `Cielo` e estou com problema na hora de fazer o tratamento da `url` de retorno, ou seja, o arquivo é chamado quando há uma atualização no pagamento, logo eu nunca acesso diretamente o arquivo, ele é chamado através da `url` pela própria `Cielo`.

O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo executar alguns códigos `sql` e também não consigo fazer o debug deles.

Quando eu apenas faço a verificação do arquivo que chega eu uso esse código:

```
$data = $_POST;
$filename = microtime(true);
$fp = fopen($filename.'.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
fclose($fp);
```

Isso gera um arquivo com todos os dados corretamente. Mas quando eu tento algo assim:

```
require_once('server.php'); //Aqui está a conexão com o banco e funções de query
$query = sql('SELECT * FROM ...');

$filename = microtime(true);
$fp = fopen($filename.'.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($query));
fclose($fp);
```

Nenhum arquivo é escrito no servidor, logo eu não consigo verificar o que está acontecendo.

Como posso contornar esse problema?

Comment: Mas você quer gravar o arquivo JSON? com seu SQL e sem tela é isso, deixa pergunta porque esta usando microtime? nem recomendo isso.

Comment: @KingRider eu preciso obter os dados do POST e executar alguns códigos SQL, por exemplo, verificar qual é o pedido de referência e depois atualizar o status do pagamento conforme recebido pelo cielo. Não preciso fazer nada com JSON, eu só estou usando ele para escrever o arquivo pois foi o único modo que encontrei de fazer um debug do que está acontecendo no arquivo de retorno. Mas eu só preciso receber o POST e fazer um SELECT e posteriormente um UPDATE

Comment: _CMCarlo: entendi se falou, querer postar dahora, veja sobre `curl` + `file_get_contents` para isso trabalhar postar. (https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php e https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Você pode debugar gerando um arquivo qualquer com as informações obtidas no PHP. Por exemplo, se você quer saber o conteúdo da variável $exemplo, faça file_put_contents($exemplo, 'log.txt', FILE_APPEND); Dessa forma, quando a URL de retorno for requisitada, ele irá gerar um arquivo com o conteúdo da variável $exemplo e você poderá visualizá-lo posteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

Passei pela mesma situação há algum tempo, e consegui debugar **consultando os arquivos de log do servidor**.

Além disso, utilizei o método [**error_log**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-log.php) do **PHP** para gravar mensagens personalizadas no arquivo de logo, a fim de facilitar a depuração dos erros.